# How to create a directory and sub directory structure with java?

Tags: java

Hello there I want to create the directories and sub directories with the java.
My directory structure is starts from the current application directory, Means in current projects directory which looks like following...

```
Images
   |
   |+ Background
   |
   |+ Foreground
          |
          |+Necklace
          |+Earrings
          |+Etc...
```

I know how to create directory but I need to create sub directory I tried with following code what should be next steps ?

```
File file = new File("Images");
file.mkdir();
```

Comment: Unrelated, but -- as an FYI -- the word is "necklace" with an "a", not an "e".

Comment: Have you had a look at the `File` class?

Comment: Thanks bro FYI :) Yes i alread tried with this  File createImages = new File("Images");
    createImages.mkdir();
    destinationDir=createImages.getAbsolutePath();

Comment: But i can't find how to create the sub directory within the images directory

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use [File.mkdir()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir()) or [File.mkdirs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) to create a directory. Between the two, the latter method is more tolerant and will create all intermediate directories as needed. Also, since I see that you use "\\" in your question, I would suggest using [File.separator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) for a portable path separator string.

Answer (score 29):

Starting from **Java 7**, you can use the [`java.nio.file.Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) & [`java.nio.file.Paths`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) classes.

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Images\\Background\\..\\Foreground\\Necklace\\..\\Earrings\\..\\Etc");

try {
    Files.createDirectories(path);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Cannot create directories - " + e);
}
```

This is a **tricky solution** (because I used only one path to go to the whole structure).

If you don't like tricky solutions, you can use 4 simple paths instead:

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("C:\\Images\\Background");
Path p2 = Paths.get("C:\\Images\\Foreground\\Necklace");
Path p3 = Paths.get("C:\\Images\\Foreground\\Earrings");
Path p4 = Paths.get("C:\\Images\\Foreground\\Etc");
```

and then call the `createDirectories` method for all of them:

```
Files.createDirectories(p1);
Files.createDirectories(p2);
Files.createDirectories(p3);
Files.createDirectories(p4);
```

Comment: This is very convenient, also when creating temporary directories during unit testing.

Answer (score 7):

You can create all parent directories by using [File.mkdirs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()).

File.mkdirs() - Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it with [`File#mkdirs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) and something like,

```
// The "/" is cross-platform safe as a path-separator in Java.
// So is "\\" but that's twice the characters!
String path = createImages.getAbsolutePath() + "/Images";
File f = new File(path);
if (!f.isDirectory()) {
  boolean success = f.mkdirs();
  if (success) {
    System.out.println("Created path: " + f.getPath());
  } else {
    System.out.println("Could not create path: " + f.getPath());
  }
} else {
  System.out.println("Path exists: " + f.getPath());
}
```

Per the linked Javadoc,

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `file.mkdirs()`, it will create  sub-directory.

```
String path = images + File.separator + Background + File.separator + Foreground + File.separator + Necklace + File.separator  + Earrings ;
File file = new File( path );
file.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding up to @ROMANIA_engineer's answer..

I used [`Path.resolve()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve-java.lang.String-) method to create sub-directories using variables lika DateTime and others:

```
private final Path root = Paths.get("target\\");
private final Path batchFilePath = Paths.get(root.resolve(LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyymmdd_HHmmss"))).toString());

Files.createDirectory(root);
Files.createDirectory(batchFilePath);
```

And the result was:
[directory/subdirectory example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y37Rl.png)