# Why sub directory can't be created in side a user generated folder in java?

Tags: java, file, io

This code generates a folder with input name given by user.
A directory with the user-input-name is created but I want subfolders inside the directory.
I have tried many times but it never gets created, please help me.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class Helper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the project folder : ");
        String proj_name = s.nextLine();
        File f = new File("c:\\"+proj_name+"\\");
         if (!f.exists()) {
            if (f.mkdir()) {
               System.out.println("Directory is created!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: It is provided by the user

Comment: Wanna see this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174784/how-to-create-a-directory-and-sub-directory-structure-with-java" ?

Comment: This code is just to create folder. Please share what you have tried to create sub-folders, and what are the errors that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your issue you want to take entries from the user and create folder and subfolder at one go.
you can use file.mkdirs() to create all the folders at once.

```
public class MakingADir {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the project folder : ");
        String proj_name = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the sub-folder name : ");
        String subFolder = s.nextLine();
        String path = proj_name + File.separator + subFolder;
        File f = new File("c:\\"+path+"\\");
         if (!f.exists()) {
            if (f.mkdirs()) {
               System.out.println("Directory is created!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Hope it helped.